# get a return value from a Daemon Process in Python

Tags: python, unix, daemon

I have written a python daemon process that can be started and stopped using the following commands

```
/usr/local/bin/daemon.py start
/usr/local/bin/daemon.py stop
```

I can achieve the same results by calling these commands from a python script

```
os.system('/usr/local/bin/daemon.py start')
os.system('/usr/local/bin/daemon.py stop')
```

this works perfectly fine, but now I wish to add a functionality to the daemon process such that when I run the command

```
os.system('/usr/local/bin/daemon.py foo')
```

the daemon returns a Python object. So, something like :

```
foobar = os.sytem('/usr/local/bin/daemon.py foo')
```

just to be clear, I have all the logic ready in the daemon to return a Python object, I just can't figure out how to pass this object to the calling python script. Is there some way?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean you want to implement simple serialization and deserialization?
In that case I'd propose to look at pickle (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to transform your data into a generic text format at the daemon side and transform it back to Python code at the client side.

Comment: `pickle` works with own serialization format, not json.

Comment: `pickle` is not really a text format; it's printable ASCII in protocol 0 (the default on Py2), so all the bytes are `< 128` and printable, but they're only half readable, in exchange for being bloated and slow. For protocols 1 and up, the text is completely arbitrary bytes, not text at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, marshaling is what you need: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/marshal.html & https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: `marshal` is mostly for Python internal use, and only supports true Python built-ins (so it can't be used with, say `Decimal`, or `datetime` objects); I'd strongly recommend using `pickle` for general purpose serialization.